# How do I specify the key for computing a SHA256 hash?

Tags: c#, hash, sha

I have had a requirement handed to me to modify an existing application to compute the SHA256 hash of a message body (basically a large string)  *using a specific key* (the key to be provided in the message header).

However in none of the .Net SHA256 classes (eg  System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed) can I find a reference to a Key property or anything like that.

Does anyone know how to do this in .Net? (This ideally has to be .Net3.5, which the application targets.)

TIA

Comment: SHA is a hashing, not a signing algorithm. It doesn't deal with keys. Most likely the requirement was to *sign* or *verify* a message, with an alrgorigthm that uses SHA256 for hashing. You need to know what algorithm to use for signing. Until you find out, [check the documentation on signatures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk8wx38z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Probably you are looking for a HMAC, it combines the calculation of a hash with using a given key.

Comment: I'm being asked to verify no tampering has taken place by verifying that the original hash of the message body agrees with a locally computed hash. Yes. HMAC is the context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've been asked to compute the Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) with SHA256. For this you will want to use the [HMACSHA256 class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256(v=vs.110).aspx) - the documentation also includes an example of how to implement this.

Comment: Thanks - I was just looking in the wrong place! I am following customer guidelines written for Java and having to 'translate' into .Net.

Answer (score 1):

There is no key for SHA256. It is hash function and returns the same value each time for the same input. This is not encryption with key.